# Java - IllegalFormatConversionException/cannot find symbol

Tags: java

Very new to java and having an issue on a lab assignment. The problem I'm having is at the bouncing part, as I have it right now it gives me `IllegalFormatConversionException: d!=Ball`. I've tried various options with my, thus far, limited knowledge, with the `printf` statement and the other error I'm mostly encountering then is Cannot find symbol. any hints to help me understand how to get this to print "bouncing 14 times" will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Ball
{
   private double size;
   public double getSize()
   {
      return size;   
   }

   public void setSize(double s)
   {
       if(s >= 0)
       {
       size = s;
       }
   }

   public void roll()
   {
   }

   public void bounce(int numberOfBounces)
   {
   }
}


public class BallApp
{
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
      Ball myBall = new Ball();  

      myBall.setSize(5); 
      System.out.printf("Ball with size %.0f\n", myBall.getSize());

      myBall.roll(); 
      System.out.println("rolling..."); 

      myBall.bounce(14); 
      System.out.printf("bouncing %d times", myBall);

      myBall.setSize(7); 
      System.out.printf("Size %.0f\n", myBall.getSize());
      }
}
```

the end outcome should read

Ball with size 5

rolling . . .

bouncing 14 times

size: 7

Comment: You are trying to print a `Ball` object as a `double`, which won't work.  What would you like to print?

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a method that returns you the number of bounces that already happened.
Like:

```
public int getBounces(){
    return this.bounces;
}
```

Then you could do

```
myBall.bounce(14); 
System.out.printf("bouncing %d times", myBall.getBounces());
```

But you have to increment the bounces counter in the bounce method first.